# Android Studio running out of memory while editing big multipart dart files

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc, android-studio-4.1

While editing big multipart dart files, the android-studio 4.1 and 4.0 is running out of memory.

No luck so far with

- invalidating caches/restart.
- refactoring dart files

Current setup

- IDE Max heap side: 4096
- Flutter plugin version on AS-4.1 is 51.0.2
- Dart plugin version on AS-4.1 is 201.9245

Previously, When Heap size was set to 3096MB
[image: heap size set to 3096]

Comment: Android studio is a memory hog. I would recommend using visual studio since it takes significantly less resources.

Comment: clearly a bug that only appeared when I've added big 'parts' as well, I've created an issue github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5034

Comment: thank you benoit jadinon